# Swift property observers, initial value

Tags: swift

The Apple documentation states:

> The `willSet` and `didSet` observers of superclass properties are called when a property is set in a subclass initializer, after the superclass initializer has been called. They are not called while a class is setting its own properties, before the superclass initializer has been called.

which means if I have some type:

```
enum State {
    case disabled, enabled
}
```

and some variable that has a `willSet` or `didSet` observer:

```
var state: State = .disabled {
    willSet {
        // do something
    }
}
```

the `willSet` observer won't get called until after I explicitly set `state` in during or after initialization of that particular instance.

Why does it work this way? As a developer, I would look at the above code and make the assumption, not unreasonably, that the observer block gets called for the original value, irrespective of instance initialization.  It seems like one heck of an anti-pattern to have to set `state = .disabled` in the initializer to trigger the observer for the initial value.

Comment: Consider what the value of `state` would be in the `willSet` block if it were triggered on the *initialisation* of the value. There is no previous value, it would just be garbage.

Comment: Interesting, I never thought about that.

Comment: I suppose also that your property observer could do any number of things, including but not limited to call instance functions which can't happen prior to initialization

Comment: Yup, that's also another good reason why it's not allowed; you could have access to a partially (or not-at-all) initialised `self`.

Comment: That makes total sense now that's its been explained to me. I think the issue might be more that the syntax seems to imply that it would get called even though that can't happen

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [Hamish's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48915486/swift-property-observers-initial-value/48915602#comment84837453_48915486) points out, in the case of `willSet` there's not a valid value that `state` could have here (and in the case of `didSet`, there's not a valid value the `newValue` argument could have).

Answer (score 1):

There's no restriction on whether `willSet`/`didSet` can access other properties of the instance. For that reason, all the instance properties need to be properly initialised before any observers are called.

On top of that, if the observer `didSet` was called when first setting a property's value, the `oldValue` variable would contain garbage, as it would never have been set.

Answer (score 1):

The way properties are handled in Swift is roughly analogous to the recommended behavior for initialization in Objective-C, notably the section "Don't Use Accessors in Initializer Methods and Dealloc" found on [this page](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmPractical.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004447-SW6). If you set a property `foo` in your `init` method, it's equivalent to setting the `_foo` instance variable in Objective-C, whereas setting `foo` outside of `init` is analogous to calling `foo`'s accessors. Basically, what used to be considered a best practice is now actually enforced by the compiler.

The reason for this is to avoid aberrant side effects caused by accessors assuming that the rest of the object's state is set up already, when in actuality it is not.

This can be worked around fairly easily, though; you can make a `fooDidSet()` method, call that from within `foo`'s `didSet`, and then also call it at the end of your initializer after calling super's designated `init`. Alternatively, you can just set the property to itself after calling super's `init` to cause its `didSet` to fire.

Answer (score 1):

Think what would happen in a situation like this:

```
class Person {
    var firstName: String {
        didSet {
            print("New full name:", firstName, lastName)
        }
    }

    var lastName: String {
        didSet {
            print("New full name:", firstName, lastName)
        }
    }

    init(firstName: String, lastName: String) {
        self.firstName = firstName
        self.lastName = lastName
    }
}
```

You'd end up using an uninitalized value for `lastName`. Which can could very well crash the app.

Swift wants to ensure object integrity, and executing observers from `init` can't guarantee this, as observers have access to all class members.